# Split a string in words and check if a word matches a list item and return that word as value for a new column

Tags: list, apache-spark, pyspark, split, apache-spark-sql

I've a DataFrame with a column `text` containing a string (or Null).

If the length of a word from column `text` is >= 6 and <= 11, then I want to match it with the `word_list`.
If a word matches, then this is the value for the new column `match`

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([
["This is line one"],
["This is line two"],
["bla coroner foo bar"],
["This is line three"],
["foo bar shakespeare"],
[None]
]).toDF("text")

word_list = ["one", "two","shakespeare", "three", "coroner"]
```

Desired result

```
+----------------------------------+------------+
|text                              |match       |
+----------------------------------+------------+
|This is line one                  |Null        |
|This is line two                  |Null        |
|bla coroner foo bar               |coroner     |
|This is line three                |Null        |
|foo bar shakespeare               |shakespeare |
|Null                              |Null        |
+----------------------------------+------------+
```

I know how to split the string in words, but after that it doesn't work anymore. I'm lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regexp_extract` to get the relevant string:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

pattern = '|'.join([rf'{word}' for word in word_list if len(word) >= 6 and len(word) <= 11])

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'match',
    F.regexp_extract(
        'text',
        rf"\b({pattern})\b",
        1
    )
).withColumn(
    'match',
    F.when(F.col('match') != '', F.col('match'))    # replace no match with null
)

df2.show(truncate=False)
+----------------------------------+------------+
|text                              |match       |
+----------------------------------+------------+
|This is line one                  |Null        |
|This is line two                  |Null        |
|bla coroner foo bar               |coroner     |
|This is line three                |Null        |
|foo bar shakespeare               |shakespeare |
|Null                              |Null        |
+----------------------------------+------------+
```

The `pattern` is something like `\b(word1|word2|word3)\b`, where `\b` means a word boundary (spaces/begin of line/end of line), and `|` means `or`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the list `word_list` as array literal and check array intersection with column `text` :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

word_list_arr = F.array(*[F.lit(w) for w in word_list if len(w) >= 6 and len(w) <= 11])

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "match",
    F.array_join(F.array_intersect(F.split("text", " "), word_list_arr), " ")
).withColumn("match", F.expr("nullif(match, '')"))

df1.show(truncate=False)
#+----------------------------------+------------+
#|text                              |match       |
#+----------------------------------+------------+
#|This is line one                  |Null        |
#|This is line two                  |Null        |
#|bla coroner foo bar               |coroner     |
#|This is line three                |Null        |
#|foo bar shakespeare               |shakespeare |
#|Null                              |Null        |
#+----------------------------------+------------+
```